# Certain images on blog are only appearing occasionally

Tags: html, css, blogs

Excuse my lack of experience, since I'm no professional.

Here's the blog I'm setting up: http://cyclesguy.blogspot.com

The problem is that the social media icons below the main logo don't appear most of the time, until I perform certain actions (so far, I've discovered that zooming and opening the console make the images appear).

I'm really not sure what's going on, and I need a little help to get this sorted. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the HTML snippet:

```
<div class='logocontainer'>
  <a class='logolink' href='https://cyclesguy.blogspot.com'>
    <img alt='Cycles Guy Logo Short' src='http://i.imgur.com/1l3re6Y.png?1'/>
  </a>
  <div id='headerlinks'>
    <a href='#'>
      <img alt='Facebook' src='http://i.imgur.com/rrBYf58.png' title='Facebook'/>
    </a>
    <a href='#'>
      <img alt='Twitter' src='http://i.imgur.com/Tj2tekG.png' title='Twitter'/>
    </a>
    <a href='#'>
      <img alt='Google Plus' src='http://i.imgur.com/0lmq5f9.png' title='Google Plus'/>
    </a>
    <a href='#'>
      <img alt='YouTube' src='http://i.imgur.com/0qf9Ghi.png' title='YouTube'/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS snippet:

```
.logocontainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
} 
#headerlinks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 40vw;
}
#headerlinks a {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
#headerlinks a img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 4vw;
  min-width: 55px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,1));
  opacity: .5;
  max-width: 60px;
}
#headerlinks a img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.logolink img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 30vw;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #000);
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #000);
  -ms-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #000);
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #000);
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #000);
}
.logolink img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(110%) drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #000);
  filter: brightness(110%) drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #000);
  -moz-filter: brightness(110%) drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #000);
  -ms-filter: brightness(110%) drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #000);
  -o-filter: brightness(110%) drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #000);
}
a.logolink {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

I'd be glad to provide any additional information that may be required.

EDIT: The issue seems to be resolved now. I made no changes to the HTML or CSS, but rehosted the images on imgur and it seems to work fine now. Earlier, I was using a direct link to http://www.iconfinder.com, which probably cause the issue. 
Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: I've edited your question to create a Snippet from the code you provided and the images are showing fine for me in Chrome v49. Are you having a problem viewing the images in the Snippet? If so, which browser are you using? If not, there may be some other code not included in your question that may be interfering with their display. EDIT: Just followed the links and the images are displaying there as well, so looks like a browser-specific issue.

Comment: The issue appears to be resolved. I rehosted the images on imgur and they load fine now.

How am I supposed to mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 0):

`#headerlinks a img {
  height: 100%;`

The problem here is that the images have height 100% which takes the height of the parent(auto) so you won't really know what height the parent has, you could just modify the height to auto, or just delete that line because it sets automatically to that.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I had previously tried removing that line but to no avail. The images would either load or not load every time I refreshed.

In any case, the issue is resolved now, after rehosting the images on imgur.